# Can I reduce the amount of noise created by metal shrinking after the fireplace is turned off?

Tags: fireplace

I have a regular US-style gas fireplace in my home. I've bought a thermostat to ensure it doesn't run 24/7 but encountered a problem: when turned off, the metal of the fireplace starts to shrink and make a characteristic cracking sound that is quite annoying, doubly so when you're trying to sleep. Is there anything I can do to reduce the amount of noise?

[image]

Comment: That sound is most likely sticking and slipping of parts not firmly affixed.  You could try taking it out and tightening all the bolts.  Or possibly find a high temperature epoxy to coat problem seams.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much from a practical standpoint that can be done. Obviously, as metal heats it expands and as it cools it shrinks again. The creaking primarily comes from seams in the firebox and the flue that move against one another as they cool at different rates.
Nothing will totally eradicate the problem other than possibly uninstalling the unit and reinstalling it with fused/welded seams to reduce the friction. It's impractical and even that would only reduce, not eliminate the noise. You might contact the manufacturer.